# cannot load such file -- app.rb (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, nginx, sinatra, passenger

Just deployed a ruby app using capistrano. I'm pretty sure I did everything as usual. Passenger though outputs the following:

```
cannot load such file -- app.rb (LoadError)
  config.ru:1:in `require'
  config.ru:1:in `block in <main>'
  /home/deploy/apps/blog/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
  /home/deploy/apps/blog/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
  config.ru:1:in `new'
  config.ru:1:in `<main>'
  /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/passenger-4.0.29/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:108:in `eval'
  /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/passenger-4.0.29/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:108:in `preload_app'
  /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/passenger-4.0.29/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:153:in `<module:App>'
  /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/passenger-4.0.29/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/passenger-4.0.29/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'

**Application root**

/home/deploy/apps/blog/current
```

The app.rb actually is in this directory.

Comment: post your config.ru file

Comment: `require 'app.rb'
run Sinatra::Application`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the below in your `config.ru` instead

```
require "./app"
run Sinatra::Application
```

It is path issues

Comment: I tried. Not enough reputation. Big thanks though! E: Oh! Done.

Comment: me?? yes I have played with it